# D (Tango) Read all standard input and assign it to a string

Tags: string, stdin, d, tango

In the D language how I can read all standard input and assign it to a string (with Tango library) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another, probably more efficient way, of dumping the contents of Stdin would be something like this:

```
module dumpstdin;

import tango.io.Console : Cin;
import tango.io.device.Array : Array;
import tango.io.model.IConduit : InputStream;

const BufferInitialSize = 4096u;
const BufferGrowingStep = 4096u;

ubyte[] dumpStream(InputStream ins)
{
    auto buffer = new Array(BufferInitialSize, BufferGrowingStep);
    buffer.copy(ins);
    return cast(ubyte[]) buffer.slice();
}

import tango.io.Stdout : Stdout;

void main()
{
    auto contentsOfStdin
        = cast(char[]) dumpStream(Cin.stream);

    Stdout
        ("Finished reading Stdin.").newline()
        ("Contents of Stdin was:").newline()
        ("<<")(contentsOfStdin)(">>").newline();
}
```

Some notes:

- The second parameter to Array is necessary; if you omit it, Array will not grow in size.
- I used 4096 since that's generally the size of a page of memory.
- `dumpStream` returns a `ubyte[]` because `char[]` is defined as a UTF-8 string, which Stdin doesn't necessarily need to be.  For example, if someone piped a binary file to your program, you would end up with an invalid `char[]` that could throw an exception if anything checks it for validity.  If you only care about text, then casting the result to a `char[]` is fine.
- `copy` is a method on the `OutputStream` interface that causes it to drain the provided `InputStream` of all input.

Answer (score 2):

Copied straight from http://www.dsource.org/projects/tango/wiki/ChapterIoConsole:

```
import tango.text.stream.LineIterator;

foreach (line; new LineIterator!(char)(Cin.stream))
     // do something with each line
```

If only 1 line is required, use

```
auto line = Cin.copyln();
```

Comment: Instead of taking individual lines, how can I take everything in a single string

Comment: @sebtm: Concatenate them. (and what if the user `yourprogram < /dev/urandom`? You'll get an infinitely long string.)

Comment: Ok is correct. But in my case is only `cat smalltextfile.txt | myprogram`.